# How to run OpenMaya.MCommandMessage without crashing Maya

Tags: python, maya, maya-api

I'm trying to get Maya's log(What it prints in script editor's output window) and add it to my custom PySide Qwidget.
Why this crashes Maya

```
QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
imoprt QtDesiner_UI
import maya.OpenMayaUI as OmUi
from shiboken2 import wrapInstance
import maya.OpenMaya as Om

def get_maya_window():
    # Get Maya window
    maya_main_window_ptr = OMUI.MQtUtil.mainWindow()

    maya_main_window = wrapInstance(long(maya_main_window_ptr), 
    QtWidgets.QMainWindow)

    return maya_main_window

class UiClass(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, QtDesiner_UI.MainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(UiClass, self).__init__(get_maya_window())

        OM.MCommandMessage.addCommandOutputFilterCallback(self.callback)
        # some PySide Widgets here
        self.console_widget = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        self.main_form_layout.addRow(self.console_widget)

    def callback(self, msg, mg, *args):
       self.console_widget.append(msg)

    def logic_stuff(self):
        #maya commands here

import UI_Window
w = UI_Window.UiClass()
w.show()
```

And this doesn't

```
def callback(msg, mg ,*args):
    console_widget.append(var)

OM.MCommandMessage.addCommandOutputFilterCallback(callback)
```

Here is the the working code that works partially. It should append log info into 'QtextEdit()' but after first operation Maya crashes(e.g. create sphere).

```
import maya.OpenMayaUI as OmUi
from shiboken2 import wrapInstance
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import maya.OpenMaya as Om

def get_maya_window():
    # Get Maya window
    maya_main_window_ptr = OmUi.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
    maya_main_window = wrapInstance(long(maya_main_window_ptr), QtWidgets.QMainWindow)
    return maya_main_window

class MainWidget(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(get_maya_window())

        self.cent_ly = MW()
        self.text_edit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        self.cent_ly.vlayout.addWidget(self.text_edit )
        self.setCentralWidget(self.cent_ly )

        self.callback_id = Om.MCommandMessage.addCommandOutputFilterCallback(self.callback)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        Om.MMessage.removeCallback(self.callback_id)

    def callback(self, message):
        self.text_edit.append(message.strip())

class MW(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MW , self).__init__()
        self.vlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()        
        self.setLayout(self.vlayout)

w = MainWidget()
w.show()
```

And this one works without crashing Maya

```
import maya.OpenMayaUI as OmUi
from shiboken2 import wrapInstance
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import maya.OpenMaya as Om

def get_maya_window():
    # Get Maya window
    maya_main_window_ptr = OmUi.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
    maya_main_window = wrapInstance(long(maya_main_window_ptr), QtWidgets.QMainWindow)
    return maya_main_window

class MainWidget(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(get_maya_window())

        self.cent_ly = MW()
        self.text_edit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        self.cent_ly.vlayout.addWidget(self.text_edit)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.cent_ly )

class MW(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MW , self).__init__()
        self.vlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()        
        self.setLayout(self.vlayout)

w = MainWidget()
w.show()

def callback(message,  *args):
    w.text_edit.append(message.strip())

callback_id = Om.MCommandMessage.addCommandOutputFilterCallback(callback)

# Om.MMessage.removeCallback(callback_id)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the callback when you close the window. I was testing your code and it worked the first time, but subsequent times froze Maya.

```
class UiClass(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(UiClass, self).__init__(get_maya_window())
        self.callback_id = Om.MCommandMessage.addCommandOutputFilterCallback(self.callback)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        Om.MMessage.removeCallback(self.callback_id)
```

Like @ababak said, the crashes happen because the object was destroyed, which happens when you close the window. So before that happens, you need to remove the callback.

Comment: Thanks it solved partially the problem now it crashes Maya after you do some operation that generates message. E.g.  create locator or select some nodes in the viewport.

Comment: @iRex That could be a previous window that has already been destroyed but still was subscribed for the callback.

Comment: @ababak how it is possible if I'm calling it only once?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shown the complete code of the first sample.

Those crashes happen when the callback is fired up but the original object has already been destroyed.

I assume you create the `UiClass` object but later it is garbage collected.
The second sample does not crash as you define your callback function in a global scope and it stays valid until you quit Maya.

Comment: Sorry I can't post whole code but I have added some lines to show general purpose of the code. I have UI that needs to be updated. How to avoid garbage collection?

Comment: Sorry, even after you added some code to your question I still don't see where you create the `UiClass` object.

Comment: I'm sorry it was misunderstood. I have added the lines. First I import the module. Then I create the object and call it with `show()`